# Get expression with regexp and capture the word

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax

I'm french and we have some quite new writing norms to make the language more "inclusive". Which means every word, conjugations and suffixes, must be feminine and masculin if adressed to everyone.

So for `C'est le président` and `C'est la présidente`, it's now `C'est lae président·e`.
Translation : `[She/He is the president]`

But it's unreadable by vocal synthesis, so I want to extract the mixed word `président·e` and read it twice (masculine way and feminine way).

By now, I use a regexp that removes every unreadable character used in new writing conventions (·-.•) `chaine.replace(/t[·\-\.•]e/gi,'te')` so it outputs the feminine word `présidente`.

But I'd like an output that gives `président et présidente`

Output when `/t[·\-\.•]e/gi` is detected : *word+t* + " and " + *word+te*

Hard to be clear about that sorry :)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

From my understanding, you want the string to be returned with both variations such that `C'est lae président·e` becomes `C'est lae président et présidente`. Assuming this is the correct interpretation of what you're trying to accomplish, you can use the following code.

The reason I go with `[^ ]+` below is that JavaScript doesn't support Unicode character well in regex, so it's the easiest way for me to demonstrate a working regex (that also works on Unicode characters such as `é`) is to match any character except the word separator character (in your case the space character).

---

### Code

```js
var s = "C'est lae président·e",
    r = /([^ ]+)·([^ ]+)/gi

console.log(s.replace(r, '$1 et $1$2'))
```

---

### Explanation

- `([^ ]+)` Capture any character except space one or more times into capture group 1
- `·` Match this literally
- `([^ ]+)` Capture any character except space one or more times into capture group 2

Comment: Thanks! I try this at once